# TCL : array is a collection of variables

Tags: tcl

I am trying to understand the difference between TCL arrays and TCL dictionary

There I get a statement :- "TCL array is a collection of variables while TCL dictionary is a collection of values"

Can somebody explain what it actually means. Programming example to understand the same will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [Chris's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70383551/7552):

A dictionary can be passed to a proc as a value

```
proc printItByValue {value} {
    puts $value
}

set myDict [dict create a 1 b 2 c 3]    ;# just another way to create a dict

printItByValue $myDict                  ;# => a 1 b 2 c 3
```

An array must be passed to a proc differently:

```
array set myArray {a 1 b 2 c 3}         ;# just another way to populate an array

printItByValue $myArray                 ;# error as shown by Chris
printItByValue myArray                  ;# only prints the string "myArray"
```

We could extract the arrays contents and pass that to a proc as a list:

```
proc printArrayByValue {arrayContents} {
    array set localArray $arrayContents
    parray localArray
}

printArrayByValue [array get myArray]
```

```
localArray(a) = 1
localArray(b) = 2
localArray(c) = 3
```

[`parray`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/library.htm#M13) is a handy utility proc to pretty-print an array.
Or, we can use the [`upvar`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm) command to link the passed *variable **name*** to the caller's stackframe.

```
proc printArrayByName {varName} {
    upvar 1 $varName localArray
    parray localArray
}

printArrayByName myArray          ;# same output as above
```

---

Note that these procs print out the array using the *local* name. To get the array to print with the same name, we can do this tricky thing to link the *local* variable to the *caller's* variable with the same name:

```
proc printArrayByName {varName} {
    upvar 1 $varName $varName
    parray $varName
}

printArrayByName myArray          ;# same output as above
```

```
myArray(a) = 1
myArray(b) = 2
myArray(c) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

With an array, these are actually three separate variables.

```
set my_array(a)  1
set my_array(b)  2
set my_array(c)  3
```

Each variable exists separately:

```
info exists my_array(a)  --> 1
info exists my_array(b)  --> 2
info exists my_array(c)  --> 3
puts "$my_array(a) $my_array(b) $my_array(c)"  --> 1 2 3
```

The name `my_array` is also recognized to exist, but is actually a special name for the *collection of the three individual variables*.  It's not really a regular variable that has its own *value*.

```
info exists my_array --> 1
puts $my_array --> can't read "my_array": variable is array
```

With a dictionary, there is one variable.  The value of the variable represent the key/value pairs.

```
set my_dict "a 1 b 2 c 3"
info exists my_dict    --> 1
info exists my_dict a  --> wrong # args: should be "info exists varName"
puts $my_dict          --> {a 1 b 2 c 3}
dict keys $my_dict     --> {a b c}
dict get $my_dict a    --> 1
dict values $my_dict   --> {1 2 3}
```

In this example, the *value* of `my_dict` is `{a 1 b 2 c 3}`.  You can pass `$my_dict` as an argument to a proc and the value is used by the proc.   You can also return a dict from a proc.  You cannot do that with an array in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Chris , that was helpful :) !!  
I have a doubt though.   
  
info exists my_array(a) --> 1  
puts "$my_array(a) $my_array(b) $my_array(c)" --> 1 2 3   
  
Here in the first three line , by ---> 1 , you mean the values hold by the three separate variables my_array(a)  , right ? Because info exists varName either returns 0 or 1   

I am just asking this for clarification   
PS : I am sorry for bad formatting (as I am new to this platform)  
  
  
Thanks

Comment: `info exists varName` returns a 1 if there's a variable called `varName` and 0 if not.

`info exists my_array(a)` will return 1, and `puts $my_array(a)` will print the value of the variable.

For formatting, you can put text inside `backticks`.   Look up Markdown rules.

Answer (score 1):

One of the big differences is that you can `trace add variable` on an element of an array, whereas you can pass a dictionary into a procedure and return it from a procedure without needing to fiddle around with `upvar` or `array get`/`array set`.

```
proc didSetOnVarElement {name1 name2 op} {
    puts "did $op on ${name1}($name2)"
}
trace add variable x(a) write didSetOnVarElement
set x(a) 1
set x(b) 2
incr x(a)
# Try comparing the output of that with what you get when you set a trace on the whole of x
```

Tracing array elements can be *really* useful, especially in Tk. So can passing things back and forth cheaply. You can't have them together though: values don't have identity in Tcl, whereas variables do (and it is exactly that identity — that name — that makes them modifiable and traceable entities while preventing them from being passed around trivially).